# Информация об ip phone через командную строку

Tags: cmd, powershell, командная-строка, voip

Линк подключен к ПК через IP телефон.
Можно ли узнать мак/ip/serialnumber IP телефона с помощью командной строки?

Comment: Я нихрена не понял. Кто такой линк? Какой телефон?

Comment: Видимо, автор вопроса хотел сказать, что к его ПК подключен IP телефон **?** (по кабелю **?**). А на этом IP телефоне функционирует Microsoft Lync **?**. Соответственнно, для получения нужной информации нужно хотя бы заглянуть в руководство IP телефона.